# How to make background color transparent in Flash Builder

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, styling, background-color

I have a list in FlashBuilder. It will allow me to choose colors for the selection, rollover, focus etc.. but I do not know how to make one of those items transparent.

I can set the alpha of the overall background, but what if I want one state just not to change color? I can't just not set them unless I create a whole new theme because they have default colors.

I'd like to know the proper mxml declaration if there is one: selectionColor="????"

Answer (score 0):

To supply a state specific attribute you just use...

```
selectionColor.stateName="????"
```

In the MXML, where `stateName` is the name of your state.

This *should* work for any element attribute.

```
 attributeName.stateName="????"
```

e.g.

```
 visible.closed="false"
```

Comment: @Slomojo.. sorry I should have written that differently.. by "state" I mean the state of the list item... hover, selected, active or what have you. Not sure what the proper word is, but I know it confuses with the actual flex states.

Comment: those list item states are also Flex states.